# Waiting progress bar while downloading Excelfile in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am calling .ashx file for download excel file from Master page menu item. But here confusion for user. user doesn't know whether download happening or not.

How can put a progress bar popup when menu item clicked in masterpage and auto disappear after download?

### MasterPage.Master

```
if e.Item.Text = "Download" Then
   Dim strUrl As String = "../Users/Download.ashx"
   ResponseHelper.Redirect(strUrl, "_black", "resizable=no, scrollbars=no")
end if
```

### Download.ashx

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
     'Some logic
     Dim filename As String = "FullExtract_" & Now.Year.ToString & Now.Month.ToString & Now.Day.ToString & ".xlsx"
     context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
     context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" & filename)
     context.Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray())
     context.Response.End()
 End Sub
```

Comment: Why did you tag your question containing only VB code with C#?

Comment: VB code. But it doesn't matter right. C# coders also can give answer.

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it wouldn't interfere with any existing restrictions, you could use [jQuery's .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function in your page to make the ajax call and handle the client notification as part of that call (*rough example*):

```
// Notify the user about downloading.

// Perform the download
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Users/Download.ashx',
    success: function(data) {
        // Notify the user it's done.
    }
});
```

Comment: In addition to what CAbbott replied, use a div with some embedded animated gif and control its visibility to show operation in progress or finished etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can get the idea from **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17979/Downloading-Files-in-NET-With-All-Information-Prog)**